# How to Inject Content Script to Local Page

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, content-script

Let me summarize the situation;

I am coding a Chrome extension that makes searches on some websites, fetches the results and then opens a new tab with a table, then puts the combined results into that table. So far so good but I have a problem.

Searching and fetching is okay. I use Handlebars Template Engine to fill the table. I have a sandbox.html;

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tablecss.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jqc-1.11.3,dt-1.10.9/datatables.min.css">
</head>


<body>
<script src="http://www.fsfoo.com/js/vendor/handlebars-1.0.rc.2.js"></script>
<script src = "https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jqc-1.11.3,dt-1.10.9/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<h1>Sonuç Tablo</h1>
<script id="some-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> <table id="mytable">
    <thead>
    <th>Kod</th>
    <th>İsim</th>
    <th>Üretici Kod</th>
    <th>Birim</th>
    <th>Marka</th>
    <th>Fiyat</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {{#parts}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{code}}</td>
        <td>{{name}}</td>
        <td>{{producer_code}}</td>
        <td>{{amount}}</td>
        <td>{{brand}}</td>
        <td>{{price}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/parts}}
    </tbody>
</table>



</script>

<script>

        var templates = [];
        var source = $("#some-template").html();
        templates['hello'] = Handlebars.compile(source);




        window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
            var command = event.data.command;
            var name = event.data.name || 'hello';
            switch(command) {
                case 'render':
                    event.source.postMessage({
                        name: name,
                        html: templates[name](event.data.context)
                    }, event.origin);
                    break;

                // You could imagine additional functionality. For instance:
                //
                // case 'new':
                //   templates[event.data.name] = Handlebars.compile(event.data.source);
                //   event.source.postMessage({name: name, success: true}, event.origin);
                //   break;
            }
        });




</script>
```

I take that sandbox.html into an iframe of my eventpage.html. Inside my event.js I send the fetched results to this iframe like this;

```
function send_results (big_data){
    var iframe = document.getElementById('theFrame');
    var message = {
        command: 'render',
        context: {parts: big_data}
    };
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, '*');
    //big_data_array = [];

        // Tab opened.
    }
```

Then I open a new tab, with my local page in my extension: tab.html. I use getUrl so it's url is like chrome-extension://nonsenseletters/tab.html. Now I want to inject a content script to tab.html so I can send the HTML from iframe to the tab.html's content script. Content script will append this HTML to tab.html's body.

I can't inject a content script to things that has chrome-extension:// sort of URL. It says I must add this host to the manifest file's permissons but nothing changes even I hardcodedly add the URL itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have complete control over the files in your extension package so just manually reference the content script in the html:

- simulating `"run_at": "document_start"` manifest.json key:

  ```html
  <html>
      <head>
          <script src="xyz.js"></script>
      </head>
  ```
- simulating `"run_at": "document_end"` manifest.json key:

  ```html
     <body>
          ..................
          ..................
          ..................
          <script src="xyz.js"></script>
      </body>
  </html>
  ```
- loosely simulating `"run_at": "document_idle"` manifest.json key:

  ```html
  <html>
      <head>
          <script async src="xyz.js"></script>
      </head>
  ```